# MenuItem does not stretch vertically in its menu

Tags: wpf, vertical-alignment, menuitem

I want the MenuItem to have a height of 24, like the menu. Currently it has 18.
I can add Height="24" to the MenuItem but I don't want to do that, and if I do, then the text won't center vertically. Why are my VerticalAlignment and VerticalContentAlignment not picked up?
Other properties of the style are picked up, so I know that the style is applied.

```xml
<Grid Background="Orange">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu Grid.Row="0">
        <MenuItem Header="Project" />
    </Menu>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Border BorderBrush="Orange" BorderThickness="2" Margin="2" CornerRadius="8,8,8,8">
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Grid>

    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
```

EDIT I tried the solution of 'nit' and moved it to a style like this:

```
<Style TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0,10,0" />
        <!-- variation on 'nit''s proposal -->
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Parent.ActualHeight}"/>
        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- variation on 'nit''s proposal -->
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MenuItem}, Path=Header}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

It seems to work in a window with e.g.

```
<Menu Grid.Row="0" Name="MainMenu" Height="24">
   <MenuItem Header="Project">
       <MenuItem Header="Open... Ctrl+O">
           <MenuItem.Icon>
              <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="/Resources/openfile.jpg" />
           </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem> </MenuItem> ...etcetera
```

It feels a bit strange to use a DataTemplate for appearance only, but a ControlTemplate breaks the    built-in MenuItem functionality. Is this a correct way to handle the issue?

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can align your menuitems :

```
       <Menu   Grid.Row="0">
            <MenuItem  Height="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Menu}}}" Header="Project" >
                <MenuItem.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource x:AncestorType=MenuItem}}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </MenuItem.HeaderTemplate>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
```

you can move this headertemplate and height binding in your menuitem style

Comment: Will try on Monday. Any idea why VerticalAlignment and VerticalContentAlignment do not have effect?

Comment: Your solution works, I tried to move it to the menuitem style, zee my edited question: what do you think about that solution?

Comment: yup.. menu/toolbars are some controls which apply their own special styling to there children... thats why we either need to override that styles or apply templates and bindings to suit our requirement...